# Avro- IDL protocol to programmatic API schema

Tags: java, json, schema, idl, avro

I want to declare an Client-Server (at the moment there are two ways mentions on Avro site `NettyServer` or `HTTPServer`) app using Avro. For that I want to define protocol using IDL files. Only thing I type in file is IDL protocol AVDL.

**1. Now how do I read the AVDL into programmatic model?**

I found the [IDLProtocolMojo](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/api/java/org/apache/avro/mojo/IDLProtocolMojo.html) but all methods protected so no access.
I know that I can use `SchemaBuilder` bu it is for defining schema in code and I want to get the `Schema` object read from AVDL definition written in hand.

I do NOT really want to use `Avro Tools` because I want the program to do it all in code no outer commands.

**2. Can simmilar thing be done also with protocol definition displayd in JSON in AVPR instead of IDL in AVDL?**